# How do I count the occurrences of a string in a PySpark dataframe column?

Tags: pyspark

Suppose I have the following PySpark Dataframe:

```
+---+------+-------+-----------------+
|age|height|   name|        friends  |
+---+------+-------+-----------------+
| 10|    80|  Alice|   'Grace, Sarah'|
| 15|  null|    Bob|          'Sarah'|
| 12|  null|    Tom|'Amy, Sarah, Bob'|
| 13|  null| Rachel|       'Tom, Bob'|
+---+------+-------+-----------------+
```

How do I count the number of people who have 'Sarah' as a friend without creating another column?

I have tried `df.friends.apply(lambda x: x[x.str.contains('Sarah')].count())` but got `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Comment: The syntax you have is for pandas. Are you looking for: `df.where(df.friends.like('%Sarah%')).count()`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [pault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5858851/pault)

```
   df.where(df.friends.like('%Sarah%')).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code:
df = df.withColumn('sarah', lit('Sarah'))
df.filter(df['friends'].contains(df['sarah'])).count()

Comment: You don't need to create a column for that. @pault has already answered above in the comments